# What happened to Edrag the daughter of Yazdgerd III?

Tags: persia, iran, sasanian-empire

After the [Sassanin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasanian_Empire) empire fell and [Yazdgerd III](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yazdegerd_III) was murdered, what happened to his daughter Edrag?

[Persian Wikipedia](https://fa.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DB%8C%D8%B2%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF_%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%85), cites [Masoudi](https://fa.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AD%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86_%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C)'s mention of three daughters Edrag (English Wikipedia has no record of any daughters)

Another daughter [Shahrabano](https://fa.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88), who was taken as a prisoner of the conquering Arab forces.

Answer (score 3):

According to page 270 of [*A Social and Religious History of the Jews: High Middle Ages, 500-1200*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Social_and_Religious_History_of_the_Je/xrUh7xGY0wIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=yazdegerd%20iii%20daughter&pg=PA270&printsec=frontcover), by Salo Wittmayer Baron, The daughter you refer to [might have been presented to the Jewish Exilarch Bustanai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bostanai#:%7E:text=Abraham%20ibn%20Daud%2C%20however%2C%5B9%5D%20says%20that%20it%20was%20the%20last%20Sasanian%20emperor%2C%20Yazdegerd%20III%20(born%20624%3B%20died%20651%2D652%5B10%5D)%2C%20who%20gave%20his%20daughter%20to%20Bostanai.) as a wife. Some confusion over who this daughter was exists, and what her actual name might have been:

> We are not even sure whether the caliph involved was 'Umar or 'Ali,
> and whether the princess was a daughter of Khosroe II or Yazdegerd
> III...The princess's name, Dara, may indeed have been but a
> Hebrew-Aramaic simplification of the **Persian name Adragh**, borne,
> according to Mas'udi, by one of Yazdegerd's daughters.

Seems close to the name you are looking for...

Comment: Is there any chance that Mas'udi mentioned in your quote is the same as Masoudi, the source quoted in the Persian Wikipedia? (and lauded as a solid historical source by the Persian Wiki)

Comment: More than likely. Spelling seems highly variable when dealing with English translations of Arabic names or phrases...